Copy post title to SEO keyword on update
I thought this might copy the post title to the RankMath SEO keyword on post update
/**
 * Function to automatically update the focus keyword with the post title
 */
function update_focus_keywords( $post_id ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rank_math_focus_keyword', strtolower( get_the_title( $post_id ) ) );
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'update_focus_keywords', 10, 3 );

...but something is wrong.

(1) Please define ...but something is wrong. (2) Do you actually want save_post (or similar) ?? ('save_post' is fired both on update and on first saving) . You may refer to this stack exchange post

What i mean is that the title is not copied into the rank_math_focus_keyword meta

add_action should be:
add_action( 'publish_post', 'update_focus_keywords', 10, 1 );
